# Rewrite database urls

Tags: mysql

Is there a query I can run on my wordpress database so that I can change all instances of

```
www.mydomain.com
```

to

```
localhost/mylocalsite.com?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/ - It helped me dozens of times.

Or try this query:

```
UPDATE tablename SET tablefield = replace(tablefield, "findstring", "replacestring");
```

Or try this method, dump the database, open the SQL file, do a find and replace in a text editor then reimport it.

Take care to backup your database prior to making any operations and changes!